# convert string to byte[] and convert byte[] to string

Tags: java

the following code is the code to convert string into byte[]

```
byte[] feedback;
feedback = "Your answer is correct and submit on time".getBytes();
```

but i found that the byte[] is containing a series of numbers, how do i convert back to string "Your answer is correct and submit on time"?

thanks

Comment: The `numbers` you see is byte/ASCII code.

Comment: Your requirement is built-in in `String` class!!! `String` has several constructor and methods for this goals. You could find your answer by reading `String` `JavaDoc`s.

Answer (score 5):

```
String s = new String(feedback)
```

But note that both `getBytes()` and `new String()` have versions that take an encoding, and you really, really, REALLY should use that, after reading [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29) constructor to get your string back: 
`String newString = new String(feedback);`

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = new String(feedback);
```

You should try first to search on the docs... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] feedback = "Your answer is correct and submit on time".getBytes ();

String backtoString = new String (feedback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your byte array back to a string using the String constructor:

```
String yourString = new String(feedback);
```

Bear in mind that both conversions are based on the default character endoding (UTF8, ...). Other methods allow setting a specific encoding; also, there is a toCharArray() method giving you an encoding-independent char[] instead of byte[].

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String u = new String(feedback, "UTF8");
```